# How to get the size of each file inside a directory in windows?

Tags: windows

I need to monitor a folder in windows Server. This folder gets updated every time. I need to get the size of the file and file name inside this folder - Just by running a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from the command line like this:

```
for %I in (test.jpg) do @echo %~zI
```

You can also pass in a file mask to get a listing for more than one file:

```
for %I in (*.doc) do @echo %~znI
```

Will display the size, file name of each .DOC file.

Use below line to display size of all the files as well as file name inside a directory.

```
for %I in (*) do @echo %~znI
```

Answer (score 0):

If sub-folders do not need it, command-line:

```
dir "<folder path>" /A:-D
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)

with

```
Get-ChildItem
```

you retive all files in the directory with the following attributes:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
```

If you need only the filename and the size you can use

```
Get-ChildItem | Format-Table Name,Length
```